# How to make one language work on all regions in android I18N?

Tags: android, internationalization

I want to let `values-zh` work on all regions of `zh`, such as `zh-rCN`, `zh-rTW`, `zh-rSG`, because any kind of Chinese language is more readable than English for most people that speak any Chinese. But `values-zh.xml` worked same as `values-zh-rCN` on my machine of MI-5X. So what is the best solution to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:**

If you are using Linux on your development machine, you can create a symlink from `values-rCN` to `values-zh` by using:

```
ln -s values-zh values-rCN
```

**Approach 2:**

You can change the language at runtime if you detect that `rCN` is used. Please keep in mind that this solution is a bit hacky and might not work in all cases.

```java
Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();

Locale sysLocale;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    sysLocale = config.getLocales().get(0);
} else {
    sysLocale = config.locale;
}

if (sysLocale.getLanguage().equals("zh-rCN")) {
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.setLocale(new Locale("zh"));
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. But it is a litter complex, and I'm using Windows. And maybe `git pull` not work for symlink.

Comment: Git handles symlinks without any problems ;) Unfortunately, I don't think that linking will work on Windows :(

Comment: I've thought about this idea too, but I don't think it will work for the application title shown in launcher. I don't know if there is a perfect idea. Thanks your answer whatever.